# How to get edited value in editable Sencha grid 4.2 for edit using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, extjs4.2

I want to edit a row in a editable row grid for Sencha Ext Js Grid 4.2, and save the edited data in database using ajax. Here is the given code for update row:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        edit: function(editor, context, eOpts) {

        var record = editor.record;
        alert(record);  
            //do your processing here, e.g.:
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'myServer/saveRecord',
                    params: { record: record }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Now I want to get the edited data, I have an alert for displaying the edited data. Its showing "undefined" in the alert. So how would I get the edited data and pass the data through ajax to save in the database. I am not finding any way to get the edited datas to pass through ajax. Is there have any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I did it, and it's working fine:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'grid_ajax/providers_edit_ajax.php',
    params: {
        id:context.record.data.id,
        npi_no:context.record.data.npi_no,
        lname:context.record.data.lname,
        fname:context.record.data.fname,
        status:context.record.data.status
    }
});
```